# JIRA: How to search for all issues that do not contain a specific value

Tags: jira

The `=!` operator returns only fields with a value that is not the specified. To find all you have to search for `(f is EMPTY OR f != "value")`.

This is ugly and clutters bigger and complex queries a lot.

It does mimick the concept of most RDBs, where a comparison against NULL is always false. Unfortunately this seems not to be the case in JIRA:

assuming `f is EMPTY` I would expect the following behaviour:

```
f is EMPTY     ⇒ true
f is not EMPTY ⇒ false
f != "a"       ⇒ false
f = "a"        ⇒ false
NOT (f is EMPTY)     ⇒ false
NOT (f is not EMPTY) ⇒ true
NOT (f != "a")       ⇒ true
NOT (f = "a")        ⇒ true
```

But instead you get

```
NOT (f is EMPTY)     ⇒ false
NOT (f is not EMPTY) ⇒ true
NOT (f != "a")       ⇒ false
NOT (f = "a")        ⇒ false
```

How do I correctly query for “all that are not a”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the support remarks, this is a bug.
I therefore post the bug link as a response to guide further seekers:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-42951

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Jira's search interface, with the JQL syntax. To search for all issues in project "My Big Project" that have a non-null fixVersion different from "Version 2", I would use:

```
project = "My Big Project" AND fixVersion is not EMPTY AND fixVersion != "Version 2"
```

It works for me  ; )